# dt.Rows.Count How to search from the textbox and show in the gridview

Tags: c#, .net, gridview

I want users to type in the Textbox and show the result on the gridview

my code is

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            String Artists = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["FleetManagementConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
            System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection con = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(Artists);

            DataSet dt = new DataSet();
            String Query = "Select AlbumName from [KazuTest].[dbo].[View_OneAlbums]  where AlbumName LIKE '%' '" + TextBox1.Text + "' '%'";
            SqlDataAdapter da;

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(Query,con);
            con.Open();
            da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

            dt.Clear();
            da.Fill(dt);

           if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            gvSubDetails.DataSource = dt;
            gvSubDetails.DataBind();
        }
        else
        {
            gvSubDetails.DataBind();
            Label1.Text = "No Records Found";
        }
        con.Close();
    }
```

but the error says

(dt.**Rows**.Count > 0) is causing error

> Error 16  'System.Data.DataSet' does not contain a definition for
>   'Rows' and no extension method 'Rows' accepting a first argument of
>   type 'System.Data.DataSet' could be found (are you missing a using
>   directive or an assembly
>   reference?)

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign the DataTable to the GridView, and then check for rows:

```
dt.Clear();
da.Fill(dt);
gvSubDetails.DataSource = dt;
gvSubDetails.DataBind();

if (gvSubDetails.RowCount > 0)  //Gridview uses RowCount, not Rows.Count
{
    //ToDo...
}
```

This should do, I believe.

Answer (score 1):

`DataSet`s do not contain rows.  They contain tables. Most likely, you should be using `dt.Tables[0].Rows.Count`

Alternativly, you may change the definition of `dt` to be a `DataTable`.